# How to delete all pandas data frames inside a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I am extracting data from a web site and I want to store it in a database. To do that I want to create and delete data frames inside a for-loop.

I tried creating a list of data frames and using a loop for deleting each element but it didn't work.

```py
tables = [df1,df2,df3]

for table in tables:
    del table
```

It does not delete the data frames and does not show any error.

I can delete them one by one using 'del' but I need a more scalable solution.

```py
del df1
del df2
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Why not simply delete `tables`?

Comment: 'del tables' delete list, not elements inside

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is index `tables` and delete a dataframe using a specific index. Note that since you're removing elements from the list while iterating, in order to avoid skipping elements start removing from the end:

```
for ix in reversed(range(len(tables))):
    # do something with tables[ix]
    del tables[ix]
```

Comment: Thank you, still can't solve it. I ran your code and it empties the 'tables' list but the data frames still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Because when deleting while iterating through the list, you are actually only deleting a reference.

if you want to delete, try to access using index:

```
l = len(tables)
for i in range(l):
    del tables[0]
```

or just pop:

```
while tables:
    tables.pop(0)
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, they delete the elements inside the tables by index but not the actual data frames. After running your code, if I type 'df1' I still see the data frame

Comment: yes this will unlink your list with the dataframe but if you first use df1 = pd.DataFrame then the ref count for the table is still not zero. So my understanding here is that you want to release the memory?

Answer (score 0):

`del` can take multiple arguments by the way:

`del df1, df2, df3`

but if you want to scale it maybe you can use dir() to see the variables in the scope and delete the ones you don't need

```
for var in dir():
      if var in tables:
          del var
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I tried it but it doesn't work as the elements inside 'tables' are data frames and not 'df1','df2' etc so it doesn't match with the variables names in dir()